# ASP.NET MVC Beta 1 - Does It Support Strongly Typed View Data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-beta1

In previous releases there were 3 ways to pass data from controller to view AFAIK (shown below).

I want to use method (2) with MVC Beta 1, but I can't find the renderView method. So what's the new syntax (if it's still possible)? Thanks in advance.

Ben.

Syntax #1: Old-school dictionary

```
ViewData["Name"] = "Moo-moo";
ViewData["Age"] = 6;
ViewData["HasFunnyFace"] = true;
RenderView("ShowCat");
```

Syntax #2: Explicitly-typed ViewData object

```
RenderView("ShowCat", new ShowCatViewData {
    Name = "Moo-moo",
    Age = 6,
    HasFunnyFace = true
});
```

Syntax #3: Anonymously-typed object

```
RenderView("ShowCat", new { 
    Name = "Moo-moo", 
    Age = 6, 
    HasFunnyFace = true 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In beta 1, use the View method:

```
return View ("ShowCat", <TYPED_DATA_SET_OR_OTHER_MODEL>);
```

The View method has replaced the RenderView method.

Answer (score 1):

Following from Kieron's comment, in Visual Studio 2008 (maybe 2005/VSE?), when you right click on your controller action, you can choose 'Add View' at the top of the context menu.

This brings up a little dialog box, which will allow you to create a strongly typed view by specifying it.